# How to send canvas content via socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, html5-canvas

I just want to copy a canvas element in canvas tag `<canvas></canvas>` and send it in real time via *socket.io* in real-time in other browsers in order to draw this element.

When I write this code in the emitter

```
socket.emit('emit_to_draw',document.getElementById('canvas'))
```

The element is empty.

How can I process?

Comment: Send `dataURI` over socket...

Comment: I done this but it is to slow. My canvas is a copy of a video element (It's a video). I seach an other solution for this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604033/draw-html5-video-in-canvas-via-socket-io?noredirect=1#comment62693205_37604033

Comment: I doubt there is any other way around..

Comment: Right now you're trying to send an element which won't work. You can use toDataURL or getImageData but they come with their own drawbacks. Why not just send the video url to each client and use the video element and redraw locally?

Comment: Thank's that what I done

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying is to send the whole canvas element when the emit is called. For that you have to convert the canvas context to base64.

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL();
socket.emit('emit_to_draw',canvas);

And when a user will receive this canvas variable, he has to draw it on the canvas.